# Close button popup doesn't work (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to create a custom pupop in javascript, this is my first time with this.

I have a problem with the close button, the "x" target correctly the div to close, but doesn't remove the "active" class at click.

https://demomadeingenesi.it/demo-cedolino/

HTML CODE

```
<div class="spot spot-2">
          <div class="pin"></div>
          <div class="contenuto-spot flex flex-col gap-3">
            <img class="chiudi-popup" src="img/chiudi.svg" />
              [---CONTENT---]
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
const tooltips = function () {
    const spots = document.querySelectorAll(".spot");
        
    spots.forEach((spot) => {
        const contenuto = spot.querySelector(".contenuto-spot");
        const pin = spot.querySelector(".pin");
    
        spot.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let curActive = document.querySelector(".spot.active");
          let contActive = document.querySelector(".contenuto-spot.show");
          const chiudiPopup = document.querySelector(".chiudi-popup");
    
          spot.classList.add("active");
          contenuto.classList.add("show");
    
          if (curActive && curActive !== spot) {
            curActive.classList.toggle("active");
            contActive.classList.toggle("show");
          }
    
          chiudiPopup.addEventListener("click", () => {
            spot.classList.remove("active");
            contenuto.classList.remove("show");
          });
      });
});
```

Comment: `curActive && curActive !== spot` this will never be true

Comment: This close the puopup on click again on the pin. And it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const chiudiPopup = document.querySelector(".chiudi-popup");
  chiudiPopup.addEventListener("click", () => {
    spot.classList.remove("active");
    contenuto.classList.remove("show");
  });
```

What the code above does is adding an click listener, but it's inside another click listener, so all it's doing is adding an click listener on the first `.chiudi-popup` that removes `.active` and `.show` from the last `spot` element.

It's hard to see if this is correct, because you haven't given us enough to reproduce the problem, but I moved the code above outside the `spot.addEventListener("click", () => {` and instead of searching the whole document with `const chiudiPopup = document.querySelector(".chiudi-popup");` the code nows only targets the `.chuidi-popup` element within the `spot`: `const chiudiPopup = spot.querySelector(".chiudi-popup");`

```js
const tooltips = function() {
    const spots = document.querySelectorAll(".spot");

    spots.forEach((spot) => {
      const contenuto = spot.querySelector(".contenuto-spot");
      const pin = spot.querySelector(".pin");

      spot.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let curActive = document.querySelector(".spot.active");
        let contActive = document.querySelector(".contenuto-spot.show");

        spot.classList.add("active");
        contenuto.classList.add("show");

        if (curActive && curActive !== spot) {
          curActive.classList.toggle("active");
          contActive.classList.toggle("show");
        }
      });
      
      // MOVED FROM THE CLICK LISTENER 
      const chiudiPopup = spot.querySelector(".chiudi-popup");
      chiudiPopup.addEventListener("click", () => {
        spot.classList.remove("active");
        contenuto.classList.remove("show");
      });
    });
```

EDIT: I missed that you have the `img.chiudi-popup` inside your container, which will trigger both event listeners. I would honestly just simplify the code and always hide the container when clicking on it again. You can still have the `img.chiudi-popup` (close image) to make it easier for the users to understand that they can click on it.

```js
const tooltips = function() {
    const spots = document.querySelectorAll(".spot");

    spots.forEach((spot) => {
      const contenuto = spot.querySelector(".contenuto-spot");
      const pin = spot.querySelector(".pin");

      spot.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let curActive = document.querySelector(".spot.active");
        let contActive = document.querySelector(".contenuto-spot.show");

        if (curActive !== spot) {
          spot.classList.add("active");
          contenuto.classList.add("show");
        }

        if (curActive) {
          curActive.classList.remove("active");
          contActive.classList.remove("show");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Here the link

https://demomadeingenesi.it/demo-cedolino/

i try your solution, but doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't give me anything to go on, and the page doesn't have the code I suggested. But you do realize that because you have `.contenuto-spot` AND the image inside `.contenuto-spot`, you will trigger two click listeners? Do a `console.log()` inside each event listener to see which triggers in which order, and then you can take it from there. I will make an edit of my post, however.

Comment: Sorry Rickard, and thank you for your support. I understand what you mean, i will upload the files with your solution, I had a solution like yours.

But whats the problem, inside some popups there are a button that if you click on it, others informations will appear.

So, each time you try to click on it, the popups will be closed and you need to open again to check the other informations.

In the second page, the list of elments, check the second "retribuzione"

Comment: I see. Popups within popups aren't a good design solution to begin with, but you could do check the event propagation (event.target) to see if you should trigger the functions of the listener or not.